# Getting an object from database using identity specification

Tags: mysql, sql

I have entered an object to a `table` in a `DataBase`. The recognition of the object is by an ID which is being put using `identity specification`.

right away, when i enter my object i want to take it's ID from the table,

how can i take it's ID if I recognize each object by it's ID (there might be same objects except for their IDs).

Is there a way to take the ID by for example the last entered to the table?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (mycol1, mycol2)
VALUES  ('val1', 'val2');

SELECT  LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: like this? for example:
        SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM mytable", CON_STR);
        DataSet dsObj = new DataSet();
        daObj.Fill(dsObj);
        return dsObj.Tables[0];